# TMDB watch providers android

Tags: java, android

I usually read answers from this forum to solve problems but now it's my turn. I'll try to explain.
I'm trying to create a movie app and now I'm trying to write code to visualize the "Watch Providers" of a movie (eg. Sky, Netflix, Amazon Prime etc).

I'm going to post the code to get the Trailers of a single movie so you can understand how I implemented my app:

TMDBApi:

```
   @GET("movie/{movie_id}/videos")
    Call<TrailerResponse> getTrailers(
            @Path("movie_id") int id,
            @Query("api_key") String apiKEy,
            @Query("language") String language
    );
```

TrailersResponse:

```
class TrailerResponse {

    @SerializedName("results")
    @Expose
    private List<Trailer> trailers;

    public List<Trailer> getTrailers() {
        return trailers;
    }

    public void setTrailers(List<Trailer> trailers) {
        this.trailers = trailers;
    }
}
```

Trailer:

```
class Trailer {

    @SerializedName("key")
    @Expose
    private String key;

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }
}
```

Json object:

```
{
  "id": 168672,
  "results": [
    {
      "iso_639_1": "en",
      "iso_3166_1": "US",
      "name": "An 'American Hustle' Special - The Art & Soul of Survival",
      "key": "LCVLdY8RcVU",
      "published_at": "2014-02-15T00:27:23.000Z",
      "site": "YouTube",
      "size": 720,
      "type": "Featurette",
      "official": true,
      "id": "58f33827c3a36807fd00d781"
    }]
```

Now the question is:

**How can I get data from Watch Providers if I have a Json Object like this:**

```
{
  "id": 168672,
  "results": {
    "IT": {
      "link": "https://www.themoviedb.org/movie/168672-american-hustle/watch?locale=IT",
      "buy": [
        {
          "logo_path": "/5GEbAhFW2S5T8zVc1MNvz00pIzM.jpg",
          "provider_id": 35,
          "provider_name": "Rakuten TV",
          "display_priority": 3
        },
        {
          "logo_path": "/peURlLlr8jggOwK53fJ5wdQl05y.jpg",
          "provider_id": 2,
          "provider_name": "Apple TV",
          "display_priority": 4
        },
        {
          "logo_path": "/tbEdFQDwx5LEVr8WpSeXQSIirVq.jpg",
          "provider_id": 3,
          "provider_name": "Google Play Movies",
          "display_priority": 7
        },
        {
          "logo_path": "/5NyLm42TmCqCMOZFvH4fcoSNKEW.jpg",
          "provider_id": 10,
          "provider_name": "Amazon Video",
          "display_priority": 40
        }
      ],
      "rent": [
        {
          "logo_path": "/5GEbAhFW2S5T8zVc1MNvz00pIzM.jpg",
          "provider_id": 35,
          "provider_name": "Rakuten TV",
          "display_priority": 3
        },
        {
          "logo_path": "/peURlLlr8jggOwK53fJ5wdQl05y.jpg",
          "provider_id": 2,
          "provider_name": "Apple TV",
          "display_priority": 4
        },
        {
          "logo_path": "/tbEdFQDwx5LEVr8WpSeXQSIirVq.jpg",
          "provider_id": 3,
          "provider_name": "Google Play Movies",
          "display_priority": 7
        },
        {
          "logo_path": "/5NyLm42TmCqCMOZFvH4fcoSNKEW.jpg",
          "provider_id": 10,
          "provider_name": "Amazon Video",
          "display_priority": 40
        }
      ],
      "flatrate": [
        {
          "logo_path": "/fBHHXKC34ffxAsQvDe0ZJbvmTEQ.jpg",
          "provider_id": 29,
          "provider_name": "Sky Go",
          "display_priority": 8
        },
        {
          "logo_path": "/y7mZSw1FV99yfawxOISBQTvtJxM.jpg",
          "provider_id": 39,
          "provider_name": "Now TV",
          "display_priority": 9
        }
      ]
    }
```

and my parameter is only movieid; the path is this: movie/{movie_id}/watch/providers

Specifying that "IT" is for the country where the movie is broadcasted. I'm interest in "IT".
How could I create the WatchProvider and ProviderResponse classes?
Thank you in advance.